# Apache Tomcat (Configuração para produção)

Tags: java, hibernate, servidor, tomcat, vraptor

Bom dia, estou fazendo um projeto e utilizando o Tomcat 8 como meu servidor. A questão é, possuo um servidor Linux para hospedar minha aplicação, mais gostaria de saber se preciso fazer alguma configuração diferente quando utilizado o Tomcat em produção.

Alguma modificação relacionado a segurança ou uso do servidor é necessária? Meu servidor é hospedado em SP e possui 16Gb de ram. É necessário algo para que o mesmo possa fazer uso da capacidade total do servidor? ou até mesmo modificar algumas configurações da jvm da máquina quando estamos utilizando a mesma para projetos em produção?

Meu projeto faz uso do VRaptor 4 e do hibernate como prioridade. Se alguém puder disponibilizar algumas dicas.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

Não existe uma resposta definitiva, mas certamente as configurações de produção podem divergir entre desenvolvimento e produção, por exemplo.

O problema é que essas configurações variam de sistema para sistema e muitas são na verdade não são feitas diretamente no Tomcat, mas no ambiente, no Java ou na própria aplicação.

Vou tentar descrever alguns itens que na verdade são básicos, mas que podem servir de início

## Memória

Faça testes de desempenho e carga analisando a memória do sistema usando algum profiler como **jvisualvm** que vêm no JDK.

Determine a memória usada pelo após a inicialização e depois de algum tempo de uso.

Defina parâmetros de memória inicial da JVM para algo perto da média de memória consumida, dessa forma a inicialização da aplicação será mais rápida porque o Java não vai precisar ficar alocando memória várias vezes.

Tente simular uma grande carga no sistema e veja como ele se comporta. Claro que isso varia de acordo com o contexto, então tente supor quantos usuários você precisa atender em horários de pico.

Para isso, considere as rotinas mais pesadas do sistema. Às vezes um sistema possui uma rotina que, quando executada, consome muitos recursos. O ideal é que tal rotina seja executado em algum tipo de fila, caso contrário, dois ou três usuários podem executá-la simultaneamente e travar o sistema.

Após analisar o sistema em estresse, defina a memória máxima de forma que seja possível atender à demanda de usuários, mas sempre tomando cuidado para não colocar muita memória e assim acabar usando paginação em disco, levando em conta todos os outros processos, como bancos de dados, por exemplo.

Sempre uso o parâmetro da JVM `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`. Se ocorrer um OOEM (Out Of Memory Error) isso vai gerar uma imagem da memória e você poderá analisar de forma relativamente fácil qual a rotina ou objeto culpado ou que está vazando memória.

## *Warming and health-check*

No servidor de produção é sempre interessante criar uma rotina executada após a inicialização da aplicação para aquecer a instância e verificar se ela foi corretamente inicializada.

O aquecimento (*warming*) é importante para garantir que o desempenho do sistema vai continuar o mesmo após uma reinicialização, por exemplo. Funciona como um botão de elevador que se auto aperta três vezes automaticamente para garantir que o elevador venha sempre mais rápido.

Brincadeiras à parte, o aquecimento e a verificação devem garantir que os caches e objetos usados nas principais rotinas do sistema estejam devidamente inicializados sem problemas.

## Codificação e localidade

Tenha certeza de padronizar o *encoding* e o *locale* tanto do sistema, quanto da JVM e do tomcat, de preferência para `UTF-8`.

O Tomcat tem por característica interpretar requisições sem um encoding definido como sendo `ISO-8859-1`. Mas existe um atributo `URIEncoding` que pode ser adicionado ao conector no `server.xml` onde você pode definir o padrão do seu sistema.

## Logs

Obviamente, o nível de logs do tomcat deve ser bem menor do que em desenvolvimento.

Enquanto em dev, o nível *debug* pode ser o padrão, em produção usamos *info* ou mesmo *warning*. Cada gravação no arquivo de log é tempo consumido. Um especialista afirmou que já viu logs sendo responsáveis por 50% do consumo de recursos de uma aplicação.

É importante achar um balanceamento entre registro e desempenho e, de preferência, ter algum mecanismo para chavear o nível de logs dinamicamente e poder fazer um rastreamento de alguma funcionalidade quando problemas ocorrerem.

Faça rotação de logs e evite gravar em arquivos muito grandes e fragmentados.

## Caching e Agendamento

Em desenvolvimento, geralmente usa-se algum mecanismo simplificado para simular caching e agendamento de tarefas.

Para produção, se houver necessidade de fazer cache de dados usando alguma ferramenta ou biblioteca, tais como *ehcache* ou *memcached*, pode ser adicionada a respectiva configuração no Tomcat para o uso adequado.

O mesmo vale para o Quartz, por exemplo. Um servidor de produção deve ter sua configuração parametrizada de acordo com as necessidades dos usuários, o que pode ser diferente de um ambiente de desenvolvimento.

## Recursos estáticos

Dependendo da demanda do sistema, você pode querer colocar arquivos CSS, JavaScript, imagens, fontes e outros recursos estáticos em um servidor web separado ou CDN, liberando assim o Tomcat para processar o que importa.

Outra alternativa é usar um proxy para fazer cache como o [Varnish Cache](https://www.varnish-cache.org/). Após uma configuração adequada, ele vai fazer cache dos recursos estáticos no primeiro acesso e subsequentemente servi-los para o usuário sem acessar o Tomcat.

Considere ainda minificar, concatenar e compactar os arquivos. Scripts e Estilos podem ter caracteres desnecessários removidos (minificação), podem ser concatenados (juntando vários arquivos em um) e vários outros conteúdos podem ser compactados (gzip) para transmissão mais rápido ao browser.

## Segurança

Requisições normais ao sistema, se ele for seguro, dificilmente vão representar algum risco ao servidor.

Entretanto, as ferramentas de gerenciamento do Tomcat que permitem monitorar e gerenciar o servidor devem estar protegidos. Para dizer a verdade, nunca vi isso ser feito diretamente no Tomcat enquanto essas ferramentas ficam exportas na web.

O que geralmente é feito é usar um proxy ou firewall para bloquear todo acesso externo que não seja direcionado especificamente para a sua aplicação em formato de requisições HTTP.

Todo o acesso às ferramentas de gerenciamento deve ser feito através de uma conexão segura, por exemplo, usando um terminal SSH e/ou uma conexão VPN.

As configurações padrão devem ser seguras o suficiente para a maioria dos casos, mas alguém pode ter mudado alguma coisa sem perceber o risco, então é bom olhar todas as [considerações de segurança na documentação](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/security-howto.html) e ver se há necessidade de alterar alguma coisa.

## Banco de dados

Independe se você usa o Tomcat para conectar-se ao banco ou faz isso em sua própria aplicação, usar um *pool* de conexões é essencial para o desempenho ao invés de criar e fechar conexões para cada acesso ao banco.

Além disso, é importante monitorar o uso das conexões para detectar vazamentos. É extremamente comum programadores desatentos esquecerem de fechar recursos num bloco `finally`, por exemplo e vez ou outra uma conexão não é devolvida ao *pool*. Logo o sistema começa a ficar lento, pois com menos conexões as novas requisições começam a esperar numa fila para acessar o banco de dados. Em breve o sistema estará completamente travado, não por um grande processamento, mas porque todas as conexões com o banco estão bloqueadas e as novas requisições ao servidor ficam eternamente esperando ou até ocorrer algum *time out*.

Assim como on caso da memória, monitore o uso das conexões durante as requisições. Se uma requisição usa muitas conexões, é hora de refatorar o sistema para fazer melhor uso delas. Caso contrário estabeleça um limite de acordo com a carga máxima de usuários esperada nos horários de pico.

Considere também duração de *timeouts*. Muitas vezes colocamos valores baixos, por exemplo, 30 segundos, porque pensamos que nenhuma rotina deve demorar mais do que isso e se hover algum vazamento de conexões o sistema se recupera em 30 segundos. Mas sempre aparece aquela rotina que demora relativamente bem mais que as outras e somos obrigados a aumentar esse valor para, digamos, 5 minutos ou algo assim. Não existe mágica.

É importante não esquecer que o desempenho de acesso ao banco não é somente ligado à execução de uma query, mas deve-se considerar o tempo para percorrer os resultados (`ResultSet`).

Certa vez eu e um colega conseguimos diminuir o tempo de resposta de uma tela de consulta de, pasmem, 30 minutos para 3. A ordem de magnitude a mais era causada por uma configuração ruim de como o driver JDBC recolhia os resultados do banco. Ele estava fazendo isso registro a registro. Fizemos um *tuning* usando variados tests e chegamos à conclusão que transmitir registros em blocos de 300 a 400 registros tinha o desempenho ótimo para aquela consulta. Mais do que isso o ganho era mínimo e o consumo de memória exacerbado.

## Limites e *timeouts*

Uploads de arquivos devem ser limitados de acordo com a necessidade do sistema. Não faz sentido, por exemplo, permitir 1 gigabyte de envio se o sistema permite apenas uploads de avatares pequenos.

Requisições demoradas são sinal de problema, mas assim como mencionei acima sobre conexões longas com o banco de dados, algumas rotinas específicas podem exigir um timeout maior.

Alguns exemplos de como configurar isso você pode [ver aqui](http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_optimize_tomcat_performance_in_production).

## Outros

Certifique-se que a [APR](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/apr.html) está instalada e funcionando. Esta é uma biblioteca de componentes nativos que melhora o desempenho do tomcat.

Espero que não esteja usando JSPs e sim algum *template engine* como Velocity. Mas, caso esteja, primeiramente minhas condolências e, sem segundo lugar, garanta que os JSPs do WAR que é implantado em produção estejam pré-compilados em arquivos `class`. Isso evita perda de tempo compilando os JSPs durante a requisição do usuário. E não se esqueça que os JSPs devem ser compiladas usando a exata versão do servidor de aplicação.

Tente sempre usar HTTPS e manter um certificado válido e não somente para o login. Todos os sistemas mais modernos suportam 100% de HTTPS.

Se tiver muita concorrência, pode ser necessário aumentar a quantidade de *threads* no pool de atendimento de requisições do servidor. [Este artigo](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Two-most-commonly-misconfigured-Tomcat-performance-settings) diz que você pode aumentar proporcionalmente ao número de núcleos, mas sinceramente nunca vi necessidade de colocar um valor muito alto.

## Considerações

Eu sei que a maioria das coisas não foram direcionadas exatamente para o Tomcat, mas fiz o possível para alinhar meus conhecimentos específicos sobre o servidor e gerais sobre aplicações Java web.

Fiz isso porque na grande maioria dos casos o fardo do desempenho está sobre a aplicação e da segurança sobre o sistema/abiente.

Comment: Foi mais que útil, me ajudou bastante. Alem de alguns tópicos que eu não tinha pensado, consegui melhorar mais o conhecimento necessário dentro de alguns tópicos. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Parabéns! Muito ajudou a entender, mas há um ponto que para mim ainda não ficou claro... Por exemplo.: definindo xms=2g e xmx=4gb, significa que de 2gb à 4gb será usado dinamicamente quando necessário? Ao contrário do xms, que é reservado no momento em que o programa, em um cenário que a JVM necessite de mais memória e o SO não tiver disponível, teremos um OutOfMemory? Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @LeandroSilva Sua interpretação está correta. A alocação dinâmica do Java depende da alocação do SO, obviamente. Contudo, dificilmente vai ocorrer uma falha como esta porque SOs usualmente fazem paginação em disco quando a memória real acaba.

Comment: @utluiz muito obrigado pelo esclarecimentos - seria pedir muito uma ajuda nesta questão? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/368747/visualvm-localmente - []´s